Is there any way to prevent the overflow of the background images?
I am having trouble to adjust the background images to stop and do not overflow at the end of the last section of my website. I cannot put them in the body background since I apply blend mode and I rotate the image trough the website.
If someone wants to help I attach also the bg image somewhere here
I expected the images to stop after the contact section that in the entire code is at the very bottom of the page. I tried to put in the page a width 100% but it scales too much in the mobile versions so right now I don't know what to do.
EDIT: [this is how the website looks right now] The background image overflows too much as you can see in the scroll bar since there is no content below the Contact section


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  gap: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 79.5rem;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: #D9D9D9;
}

.paper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0;
  background-color: #D9D9D9;
  mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
}

.paper img:nth-child(2) {
  rotate: 180deg;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.paper img:nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: -40px;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

#contact {
display: flex;
padding: 7.551svh 0rem 12.945svh 0rem;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
align-self: stretch;
}



#contact .content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

#contact .content h4 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 11.97916svw;
    color: var(--primary-light);
    font-family: var(--title);
    font-size: 5.394svh;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: normal;
}

.content .main {
    display: flex;
    padding: 6.688svh 0rem 0rem 1.5625svw;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.main a {
    color: var(--primary-light);
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: var(--title);
    font-size: 21.575svh;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.main .bottom {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    gap: 5.394svh;
    align-self: stretch;
}

.main .bottom .divisor {
    display: flex;
    gap: 4.583svw;
    align-items: center;
    align-self: stretch;
}

.bottom .divisor hr {
    flex: 1 0 0;
    border-radius: 2svh;
    border: 0.129svh solid var(--primary-light);
}

.bottom .divisor h3 {
    color: var(--primary-light);
    font-family: var(--title);
    font-size: 4.315svh;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.main .bottom .contact-socials {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    align-self: stretch;
}

.main .bottom .contact-socials a {
    color: var(--primary-light);
    font-family: var(--title);
    font-size: 4.315svh;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
}
<section class="contact" id="contact">
  <div class="content">
    <h4>Do you have a project in mind?</h4>
    <div class="main">
      <a href="mailto:kianbonci@gmail.com" target="_blank">Let’s Connect</a>
      <div class="bottom">
        <div class="divisor">
          <hr>
          <h3>or</h3>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-socials">
          <a href="https://www.behance.net/kianboncilli" target="_blank">Behance</a>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/kian_boncilli/" target="_blank">Instagram</a>
          <a href="" target="_blank">Linkedin</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<div class="paper">
  <img src="/assets/imgs/bg/bg.png" alt="bg img">
  <img src="/assets/imgs/bg/bg.png" alt="bg img">
  <img src="/assets/imgs/bg/bg.png" alt="bg img">
</div>




Please [edit] and change the snippet I made into a [mcve]

Hint: You can use f.e. https://placehold.co to embed images that will be visible to all of us. (If such generic placeholder images allow us to see what the problem is supposed to be in the first place, because from your current description, I can't even tell for sure.)

If it is important for understanding of the question that we see actual images, you can load them through the editor (use the icon of a mountain).

If you could add a screenshot of the design it would be great for visual interpertation
If i understand the question correctly, I would set a specific heigth and width for the images. And for different viewporst different height and widths.
What you also could do, but that would be really MacGyver style, is to use an empty div with the background color so you can overlay that on the area that you do not want to have the image backgrounds.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
